# Do any of you guys know OOP in Lua?

Tags: oop, lua

so I found that there's no classes in lua, how can we do OOP with functions or other ways?

```
--I heard that we can do OOP like this:
local className = {}
local function className.my_function(_t)
    --the program
end
```

but it can only make one object.....

Comment: https://www.lua.org/pil/16.html

Answer (score 2):

A good place for storing function/methods is the metamethod __index of a metatable.
Look at a string. The datatype is metatabled with an __index referencing the string library...

```
-- Using a string like an object with attached methods
print(_VERSION:upper():reverse())
-- Prints out: 4.5 AUL

tprint = function(tab) for k, v in pairs(tab) do print(k, "=>", v) end end

tprint(getmetatable(_VERSION).__index)
-- Print out all attached string methods/functions
```

So try by yourself to attach table functions as table methods...

```
my_oop = setmetatable({1, 2, 3, 4, 5},{__index = table})

my_oop:concat("\n")
-- Puts out table values with attached method: concat()
```

So feel free to attach whats usefull for your datatype.